# Как поменять встроеный фон AIMP в закрепленых плитках Windows

Tags: windows

Нужно удалить желтый фон AIMP и заменить на стандартный виндовс (как на картинке), уже много разных ресурсов перечитал и нигде никак не могу найти с чем это связано.

[image: Фон AIMP Тогда как остальные стандартного цвета]

Comment: Есть вероятность, что это не настраивается. Попробуйте к разработчикам AIMP обратиться напрямую, например через [форму обратной связи](http://www.aimp.ru/?do=feedback).

Comment: как вариант https://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-custom-start-tiles